# When will Eclipse Juno (4.2) be coming to Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse

There are [many](http://akovid.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/installing-eclipse-juno-42-in-ubuntu.html) [web](http://www.blogs.digitalworlds.net/softwarenotes/?p=54) [pages](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEITkgLpcVE) that describe how to install Eclipse Juno on various versions of Ubuntu, but I was wondering when it will be released properly in the default Ubuntu repositories?

I notice that the new release of 13.04 is [still at version 3.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/eclipse). Is there a chance of it making it in to the 13.10 release?

> **EDIT**: As I state in my original question, there are may web pages that describe how to install Eclipse Juno, so **please do not answer with an installation guide for 4.2.**

Comment: Hi - this question is not really answerable at the moment - simiilar questions in the past have been closed since they really discussion/debating points.   I've returned your bounty.  Please file a bug report on launchpad or contact the maintainers via IRC.

Answer (score 2):

The main repositories of 13.04 are **not likely to be upgraded to the latest release of Juno now that they're released**, for reasons explained in [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) .  If the Eclipse team has a PPA with Eclipse Juno, then you can use that.

Otherwise the latest Eclipse software will need to be downloaded and run manually.

Perhaps it will be backported to 13.04 (or earlier), if the software is available in the next version of Ubuntu.  But only if someone can make sure it builds and runs correctly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I was using the wrong vernacular. I have updated my answer to use the correct term.

Comment: You're welcome, @ltn100.  This is still a valid answer, as it links you to a related question/answer combination here that I had initially posted and received a canonical answer for, which generally answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse.org, download Juno, unzip it, go find the executable, run it. I personally prefer this method, so I can have various instances of eclipse with different plugin setups. They probably won't fix their repos.

Answer (score -1):

I have no trouble with the archive version. I usually install the repository version to make sure I have all the dependencies, then download and unpack the archive from eclipse.org, which I then just run from my home folder.

If anything, it's easier to update because you don't have to cope with the schizophrenia that results from the mid air collision of the Eclipse update mechanism (p2) and the Ubuntu package management.